# How to properly model complex hierarchy and interface with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I'm trying to setup a simple contact application with `Person` and `Company` deriving from a base class called `Atom`:

```
Atom
  +-Contact
      +-Person
      +-Company
  +-ContactPhone
  +-ContactEmail
```

I want to add `ContactPhone` and `ContactEmail` to the above.  The *tricky* operation that I want to do is to merge two persons and have their corresponding emails and phones merged automatically.  Let's say we call these two persons the winner and the looser, I'm looking to do the following update:

```
update ContactPhone CP set CP.contact_id=winnerid where CP.contact_id=looserid
update ContactEmail CE set CE.contact_id=winnerid where CE.contact_id=looserid
```

Even further, I would like `ContactPhone`, `ContactEmail`, and perhaps some other `ClassConnectedToAContact` to implement a `ConnectedToContact` interface and do the following query:

```
update ConnectedToContact CTC set CTC.contact_id=winnerid where CTC.contact_id=looserid
```

And have that update run over all contacts that match the criteria and do the update. So far I have come to this **not working** structure.  Perhaps you can send me in the right direction to making it work.  Perhaps it needs just a little bit of tweaking.

**class Atom**

Provides unique identifier across all database elements. As well as create, update, delete, status for all objects

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Atom {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
...
}
```

**class Contact**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Contact extends Atom {
    public abstract Collection<ContactPhone> getPhones();
    public abstract void setPhones(Collection<ContactPhone> phones);
    public abstract Collection<ContactEmail> getEmails();
    public abstract void setEmails(Collection<ContactEmail> emails);
    ...
}
```

**class Person**

Stored in its own table.

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Contact {
    ...
}
```

**class Company**

Stored in its own table.

```
@Entity
public class Company extends Contact {
    ...
}
```

The crucial part is when I incorporate the `ContactPhone` and `ContactEmail` that are `ContactConnected`.

**interface ConnectedToContact**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public interface ConnectedToContact {
    public Contact getContact();
    public void setContact(Contact contact);
}
```

**class ContactPhone**

```
@Entity
public class ContactPhone extends Atom implements ConnectedToContact {
...
}
```

**class ContactEmail**

```
@Entity
public class ContactEmail extends Atom implements ConnectedToContact {
...
}
```

Comment: is solving this in code really too slow?

Comment: It is not about being slow.  At some point there will be many `ConnectedToContact` entities.  Trying to update all the relations in a large group of developers can lead to errors.  Particularly when new entities are incorporated.  I'm just trying to protect from myself down the road... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

i would implement it in code something like

```
public void Merge(Contact contact1, Contact contact2)
{
    session.beginTransaction();
    Contact winner = null;
    Contact loser = null;
    // determine winner and loser

    // Hibernate should know which entities implements ConnectedToContact
    List<ConnectedToContact> loserData = session.createCriteria(ConnectedToContact.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("Contact.Id", loser.getId()))
        .list();

    for(ConnectedToContact item : loserData)
    {
        item.setContact(winner);
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Comment: That is exactly the type of code I'm using.  The problem is that the query returns null for some reason.  I'm thinking it has to do with the way I declare `@Entity` and `@MappedSuperclass`.

Comment: then it would be best to fix this instead